# How to make a JPA Column insertable only during JUnit tests?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Column(insertable = false,
            updatable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime modification;
}
```

In general, the timestamp should be managed by mysql only, not by the application using the entity. Thus `insertable=false`.

But during a `junit` itest, I want to forcibly change the modification timestamp to a fixed value. Which would only be possible if `insertable=true`.

Question: is it possible to change the attribute only during testing?

Comment: Do it outside of JPA.  Use a JdbcTemplate to set up your test, run it, then clean up the changes to the database goes back to the original state.  What is JPA buying you here?  I'd use JdbcTemplate.  It's simpler.

Comment: Shouldn't updatable also be false then?

Comment: You should be able to do it with raw SQL using JdbcTemplate if the schema doesn't prohibit it.   The prohibited annotation is a Hibernate construct.  It isn't enforced if you aren't using Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a orm.xml in the test/resources/META-INF directory and override the mapping with XML.

The tags in the XML are the same as the annotations but instead of camel-case in kebab-case.

Please find the whole spec here:
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/metadata_xml.html

@Gimby is right the orm.xml is additive so you can just override what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.1"
                 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm">

    <package>your package here</package>

    <entity class="MyEntity">
        <attributes>
            <basic name="modification">
                <column insertable="true" />
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: "But you have to specify the whole mapping MyEntity in the XML file" - I don't think this is true for the orm.xml, it should be additive. What you say is true for a hibernate mapping file.

Comment: It's hard to tell without testing. Even the spec is not 100% clear: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1560344396_53b19b6cc3d988220ab189e1c5e2d283 I will go ahead and create at test. Stay tuned :-)

Comment: @Gimby Edited my answer. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Worth noting that although this is technically the correct answer for the question asked, I do support Duffymo's suggestion to use a more direct SQL approach to bootstrap test data. This solution breaks the reality. But you know, Stack Overflow does not exist to pass advice, it exists to have answers to questions.